# SAS will merge delete duplicate rows?

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
DATA _quotes_merged;
    merge TICKERS_NBBO (IN=C)
          _quotes_processed (IN=D)
    ;
    by SYM_ROOT;
    if C and D;
RUN;
```

In table C, there is a variable named `SYM_ROOT` which contains a set of unique symbols or stocks.

In table D, there is also a variable named `SYM_ROOT`, but there are lots of duplicate rows with the same symbols.

Now, I want to keep those rows in D only when a match in C is found, **without** deleting the duplicates. I also don't want any void values (that's why I am using `if C and D` instead of `if C`).

I was wondering if my code above work as planned?

Comment: Should be fine. There is nothing in the code that should delete duplicates. Is there something that seems like it isn't working as you want?

Comment: Nope I just wanted to confirm haha